# How to show specific 2 rows at the top without order and then sort the rest by order using SQL DISTINCT, UNION

Tags: sql-server, distinct, union

I have a country table with Id, Name with duplicate records. I am Using DISTINCT and UNION to show particular 2 country names  Ireland and England at the top and rest all after By order name like below in SQL server

```
create table country (id int , name varchar(50));                      
insert into country (id, name) values( 1, 'Kuwait');                
insert into country (id, name) values( 2, 'Australia');             
insert into country (id, name) values( 3, 'Canada');
insert into country (id, name) values( 4, 'spain');
insert into country (id, name) values( 5, 'Turkey'); 
insert into country (id, name) values( 6, 'Ireland');
insert into country (id, name) values( 7, 'England');
insert into country (id, name) values( 1, 'Kuwait');                
insert into country (id, name) values( 2, 'Australia');             
insert into country (id, name) values( 3, 'Canada');
insert into country (id, name) values( 4, 'spain');
insert into country (id, name) values( 5, 'Turkey'); 
insert into country (id, name) values( 6, 'Ireland');
insert into country (id, name) values( 7, 'England');
DESIRED OUTPUT:
id    name 
-----------
  6   Ireland
  7   England
  2   Australia
  3   Canada
  1   Kuwait
  4   Spain
  5   Turkey
```

Tried with DISTINCT & UNION in SQL QUERY:but names are not ordered after 3 row

```
 select distinct id,name from country where id in (6,7)
 union
 select distinct id,name from country where id not  in (6,7)

 id   name 
-----------
  6   Ireland
  7   England
  1   Kuwait
  2   Australia
  3   Canada
  4   Spain
  5   Turkey `
```

also tried with ORDER BY CASE:

```
  select distinct id,name from country where id in (6,7)
  union
  select distinct id,name from country where id not  in (6,7)
  ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN id = 6 and id = 7  -- whatever identifies that row
  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

ERROR:ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: ORDER BY with CASE should be the solution. You don't need to filter for the id's and use UNION. Just select distinct id, name from country + your ORDER BY CASE statement. And if you need to order after this, you just put a comma and use id or name.

Comment: select distinct id,name from country 
ORDER BY CASE 
 WHEN id = 6 and id = 7  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END  givening error:ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: OK, then put the distinct in a subquery as in Andrey Nikolov's answer

Comment: Thanks, David. Andrey Nikolov's query returns the right answer but will wait if we get any better answers. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, that is a correct answer if you want to order by name. If you want to order by id, you need to put your CASE expression + ,id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no guaranteed order of the returned result, unless order by is specified. Even if you find a query, that returned the rows in the desired order, on next run, tomorrow, or at client's site, it will not return them in the same order. So you **must** add an order by clause. You need to sort on some artificial values, like this:

```
declare  @country table(id int , name varchar(50));                      
insert into @country (id, name) values( 1, 'Kuwait');                
insert into @country (id, name) values( 2, 'Australia');             
insert into @country (id, name) values( 3, 'Canada');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 4, 'spain');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 5, 'Turkey'); 
insert into @country (id, name) values( 6, 'Ireland');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 7, 'England');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 1, 'Kuwait');                
insert into @country (id, name) values( 2, 'Australia');             
insert into @country (id, name) values( 3, 'Canada');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 4, 'spain');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 5, 'Turkey'); 
insert into @country (id, name) values( 6, 'Ireland');
insert into @country (id, name) values( 7, 'England');

select id, name from (
select distinct id, name
from @country) t
order by case name when 'Ireland' then 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1' when 'England' then 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa2' else name end
```

Comment: This is a clever solution. Just for clarification, you could mention the reason for the subquery, so that people know that otherwise they will get an error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified". One possible way to avoid the subquery and distinct is to add GROUP BY id, name

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. It works perfectly as per my requirement.